# Improving the linear search technique?

Tags: java

I'm afraid we have a bit of a sadistic instructor on our hand, because I honestly did not understand this question and never found the answer in the text book, nor searching the internet.

**"2.   If the list is already in sorted order, how can you utilize this information in improving the linear search technique? Show your improvement in the algorithm of linear search."**

As far as I know, Linear Search have only one job, which is examining each element sequentially. HOW can it be improved? What I know is the Linear Search Big-O notation is O(n) and that O(n) is the worse case performance since the element is placed the very last in the list or array. I was about to answer that question by switching to binary search but then I found that binary search would take even longer since it'll take n/2 times to locate, n/4, n/8 and do on and linear search would take as much time.

Let me know if I'm getting this question the wrong way or I'm missing something about this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can choose a different starting point

Comment: If it is a linked list then locating the middle element really needs O(n/2). For an `ArrayList` it would be just O(1)

Comment: I did, and as I said above, Binary search would be slower for slower for sorted list.

Comment: You have to specify the data-structure that you are searching in and all other factors, otherwise trying to optimize is pointless.

Comment: A math question:  is the list numerical and is it bound by the range of integers?  That is to say, there is a clever math approach that can be taken if the values you're sorting against are known to be numerical only (e.g. no lexicographical strings or decimals) which can be used to optimize the approach.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Read the description of the algorithm again.

Comment: @leonardkraemer:  ...did you (and someone else) miss the part where they said it was a list or array?

Comment: @Makoto no, but still it is not clear, because he says that binary search is slower, so there must be a catch. Probably this statement was just wrong though.

Comment: Binary search requires access an element by index in O(1) time to be achieve O(lgn) time, this is not possible in a traditional linked list implementation.

Comment: Binary search is just as slow as far as I know, and the reason for that is that it takes n/2 times to locate the middle element, n/4 times to locate either of the sub interval and look up time multiply with each step. Thus we would expect n times to locate an element. I don't know if that's an improvement over linear search. That's why I'm not convinced that binary search is the answer. Beside it's mentioned in the text book "Big Java" that Binary is just as slow in linked searching.

Comment: @user9578589 you made the assumption that a list is a linked list that needs O(n) to locate an element. In 99.99% of the cases, a List is backed by an array, because it's much faster. looking up an element in a list backed by an array is O(1)

Comment: Binary search is O(lg n) since you're always reducing your search area by half every time you perform a branch.  That is to say, if you know your value is somewhere between 1 and 20 and you have 100 elements, you'll only make ln(100)/ln(2) ~ 7 choices to get to the right value.

Comment: @JBNizet:  (Playing devil's advocate; if you look at the first or last element of a linked list that too is also O(1).  There are cases in which using a linked list is faster or more preferable to an array; for example, queueing and stacks.)

Answer (score 3):

> I found that binary search would take even longer since it'll take n/2 times to locate, n/4, n/8 and do on and linear search would take as much time.

It depends on whether `List::get(int)` is `O(1)` operation or an `O(N)` operation.  That depends on the list class.

- For a `LinkedList` it is `O(N)`.  Calling `get(i)` has to follow the links `i` times starting from the head of the list.
- For an `ArrayList` it is `O(1)`.  Calling `get(i)` is just an `array[i]` operation on the list's element array.

Redo your calculations for binary search with the assumption that `get` is `O(1)` and (if your analysis is correct, and your understanding of binary search is correct) you should get `O(logN)` for lookup by value using binary search.

(But yes, binary search on a linked list is not an optimization relative to linear search.  It would be `O(N^2)` - an anti-optimization, given that linear search is `O(N)`.)

---

> I'm afraid we have a bit of a sadistic instructor on our hand.

Possibly.  An alternative explanation is that the instructor is trying to encourage you to improve your analytical thinking skills by getting you to work things out for yourself.  That includes figuring out your mistakes, including possibly incorrect assumptions you are making.  Sometimes, the best way to learn from a fundamental mistake is "the hard way".